# Determining whether (x,y) points in the input constitute a function

Tags: beginner, haskell, io, monads

I'm learning Haskell, and I've finally gotten around to coding up some Haskell. This code passed my tests.

This code takes a line from standard in which tells it how many cases it's going to have (1 to 5), and for each case, it takes a line telling it how many pairs (max of 100) of x's and y's it will get (integers from 0 to 500), and it should print `YES` if x to y is a function, and `NO` otherwise.

e.g. with a file called `input`:

```
2  
2
1 1
2 1
2
1 1
1 2
```

The following command should work like this:

```
$ runhaskell main.hs < input
YES
NO
```

In my source code the only difference is I have two blank lines for style instead of one between each group of code. My `main.hs`:

```
import Control.Monad (replicateM_, replicateM, forM)
import Data.String (words)

main = do
  times <- readLn :: IO Int
  replicateM_ times input_is_a_function

input_is_a_function = do
  n_inputs <- readLn :: IO Int
  inputs <- replicateM n_inputs getLine
  if (null inputs) || (is_function inputs) then
    putStrLn "YES"
  else
    putStrLn "NO"

is_function inputs = is_func ([map read $ words i | i <- inputs] :: [[Int]])

is_func (x_y : rest)
  | rest == [] = True
  | otherwise  = (no_other_y x_y rest) && (is_func rest)

no_other_y [x1, y1] rest
  | rest == [] = True
  | otherwise  = this_y_ok && (no_other_y [x1, y1] (tail rest))
      where
        this_y_ok = not (x_is_target && y_not_equal)
        x_is_target = x1 == head (head rest)
        y_not_equal = y1 /= ((head rest) !! 1)
        -- if target is false, y is ok.
        -- if target is True, y must be equal
```

The algorithm starts with the first pair of x and y, and does a search for a repetition of x and determines if it matches y or not. Any found x with a mismatch on y should stop the algorithm.

I come from a Python background, so I tend to use snake-case and idioms I am more immediately familiar with (list comprehensions FTW!), but I want to learn idiomatic Haskell.

I also value readability. I could probably have better names. Perhaps more typing would improve readability, but I tried to take as much advantage of Hindley-Milner type inference as I could.

Please address efficiency, typing, style, naming, or any other important issues you identify.

On my workflow: I've been using a basic ghc (7.10.3) from the Ubuntu repos with a test file and that command mentioned above.

Is there a better approach? e.g. a way to watch the file and run tests as I code and save? In Haskell?

Answer (score 4):

Let's condense this down. What you're trying to check is that for any given x, the y values you're told are all the same.

Now let's try to express this as succinctly as possible:

Let's start with a few simplifying assumptions. All your x and y values are going to be integers. Furthermore, let's assume we handle them as Tuples and not as Lists. This enables a somewhat cleaner signature for our types

We start with a list of points and in the end we want a boolean to drop out. Our type signature accordingly looks like this:

```
isFunction :: [(Int, Int)] -> Bool
```

This function can be decomposed into a few steps. First we need to group by the x values.

```
isFunction points = -- we'll fill this in later
   where
   grouped = groupWith fst points -- fst accesses the first item in a tuple
```

now that we have all points grouped, we need to examine their y values

```
   ys = map (map snd) grouped -- snd gets the second item in a tuple
```

And now we want to make sure that every group of y values is always the same value.
For this I'll use a bit of a hack

```
   areEqual = map (\l -> all (== (head l)) (tail l)) ys
```

What this does is a bit hard to grasp at first glance, but types will help us understand.

Let's fill back the types for all the stuff we had until now:

```
grouped :: [[(Int, Int)]]  -- List of List of Points
ys :: [[Int]]  -- List of List of Integers
```

Now let's examine what this does in `areUnique`. We know that none of the lists in `ys` are empty. That's very useful for accessing the first element in the list and setting it as baseline for the rest of the list we're examining. All items in a single list (and accordingly belonging to a single x) must be pairwise equal. This explicitly means they must be equal to the first item.

That's how we can use `all (== (head l))`. That line could also be written as the following:

```
   areEqual = map (\yGroup -> all (== yGroup!!0) yGroup)
```

Now we have in `areUnique` a `[Bool]`, each of them indicating, whether the group is consistent.

That allows us to formulate the final result of `isFunction` we omitted above:

```
isFunction points = all id areEqual
```

So now we have a pretty function that will do the work of your `is_func`, including all the work of `no_other_y`. We need to `import GHC.Exts` for it to work, because it provides `groupWith`. If you don't have GHC on your system, you will need to write a replacement, but that's probably a good exercise in itself. Only that much: sorting before grouping helps a **lot**.

A nice sideeffect of this is that we're reducing the time-complexity from \$\mathcal{O}(n^2)\$ to \$\mathcal{O}(n \log n)\$

---

Now aside from this move away from list comprehension into a more explicit model that should additionally be quite a bit faster, there's not that many things to say about your code.

Granted, you largely ignore types (which is something that I personally do exactly the opposite of) and you're using python naming conventions, which only clashes with `readLn`, `getLine` and `replicateM_`.

This is what we got for now:

```
import GHC.Exts  (groupWith) 

isFunction :: [(Int, Int)] -> Bool
isFunction points = all id areEqual
   where
   grouped = groupWith fst points
   ys = map (map snd) grouped
   areEqual = map (\l -> all (== l!!0) l) ys
```

Now let's get a bit fancier. We can inline a few of these definitions:

```
areEqual = map (\l -> all (== l!!0) l) (map (map snd) grouped)
```

notice the repeated use of `map`. We can get around that by using function composition `(.)`:

```
areEqual = map ((\l -> all (== l!!0) l) . (map snd)) grouped
```

interestingly it's not necessary to map to the y value alone. While semantically appropriate, the x values already should be the same. This allows us to drop the mapping:

```
areEqual = map (\l -> all (== l!!0) l) grouped
```

Now we can inline `grouped` to obtain (which uses `$`, the self closing parenthesis):

```
areEqual = map (\l -> all (== l!!0) l) $ groupWith (fst) points
```

And to top it off, this can be inlined into our `all`, which gets us to:

```
isFunction points = all id $ (map (\l -> all (== l!!0) l)) $ groupWith fst points
```

At this point we replace our fancy self-closing braces with function composition to obtain

```
isFunction points = (all id) . (map (\l -> all (== l!!0) l)) . (groupWith fst) points
```

which can then be reduced to:

```
isFunction = (all id) . (map (\l -> all (== l!!0) l)) . (groupWith fst)
```

That in turn can be simplified to (hat tip to @Gurkenglas):

```
isFunction = all (\l -> all (== l!!0) l) . groupWith fst
```